# I want to update a min value of a number field in a html form with a value returned from an ajax post without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm currently working on an auction site. I have a form where If a user makes a new bid, the new bid gets posted via ajax to a php file to update the database and then returned to get outputted as the new highest bid within html.

```
   var aucid = "<?php echo $auctionID; ?>";

   $.ajax({
   url: "JqueryPHP/Price.php",
   method: "POST",
   data: {'auctionid': aucid },
   success: function (result) {
    $('#price').html(result);

    }
         });


        }, 333);


  $("input[name='auctionid']").val("<?php echo $auctionID; ?>");

  $('form').bind('submit', function (event) {


   event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 



      $.ajax({

       type: 'POST',
        url: 'JqueryPHP/HighestBid.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });
```

---

```
  <form> 
        <input type="number"min="<?php echo $startingprice?>"  style="width: 
       10em;" size="35" 
       name="newbid" id="newbid" tabindex="1" class="form-control"  
        placeholder="New Bid €" value="" required>
                                                <br>

                        <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="2" class="form- 
    control btn btn-login" style="width: 14em" value="submit">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              <input name='auctionid' style="display:none"/>  



                                                  </form>
```

---

```
      <?php
      //JqueryPHP/Price.php
     $auctionid = $_POST['auctionid'];
     $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'auctionsite');
     $sql='SELECT  * FROM auction WHERE auctionid="'.$auctionid.'"';
      if($rs=$conn->query($sql)){ 

   $row=$rs->fetch_assoc();
   $highestbid = $row["highestbid"];
   }

        echo $highestbid;
```

---

```
 //JqueryPHP/HighestBid.php

 if (isset($_POST['newbid'])) 
 {
  $newbid=$_POST['newbid'];

      $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  $auctionid = $_POST['auctionid'];
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'auctionsite');
 $sql = "UPDATE auction
    SET highestbid = '$newbid', useridhighestbid = '$userid'
    WHERE auctionid = '$auctionid'";
   if(@$conn->query($sql)){  //execute the query and check it worked    
                        return TRUE;
                    } 

   }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The problem is that a person can enter a bid lower than the current highest bid which you shouldn't be allowed to do. When the new highest bid gets updated, the minimum price for a bid a person can enter is still the starting price because i'm not sure how to use the new highest value returned by the ajax post to update the min value in the form with the new highest price.

I definitely know that I should use javascript instead of php to update the min value in the form, I just don't know how to go about it because I'm very new to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of the input field with JavaScript, you would use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('newbid').value = valueReturnedFromAjax;
```

You would just need to replace `valueReturnedFromAjax` with the new value you got back. The PHP only gives the input value its initial value, so it will get overridden.

Comment: var minval = document.getElementById('newbid');
minval.min = result;

worked :)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
HTML
<input type="number" id='price' onblur='checkMinPrice("idOfItem")'>

JS
function checkMinPrice(idOfItem){

var enteredPrice = $("#price").val();
// use ajax here to fetch minimum price from server.
// suppose we have fetched price and it is saved in "MinPrice" variable

if(MinPrice >= enteredPrice){
    //give alert or any other type of error here.
    alert("Entered price must be greater than minimum price");
    $("#price").focus(); // move the curson to price field to ask him to enter higher price.
}
}
```